# Can anyone help me with a question about Interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, interface

I've been given a question that says this.

Create the IPeople Interface: Teachers and Students have much in common but some minor differences. Create an interface to expose all commanlity between them. You will need to modify the Teacher and Student partial classes in order for them to implement this interface.

Now I'm not entirely sure what this is telling me to do. Teachers are made up of : ***TeacherId, FirstName, LasteName, DateOfBirth, AnnualSalary, DepartmentId*** and Students are made up of : ***StudentId, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, AverageScore, DepartmentId.***

I would guess then that the commanality is FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth and DepartmentId. Also a ***Teacher*** teaches a ***Course*** and ***Student*** takes a ***Course***.

Now I believe I would need to modify the Partial Class of Teacher and Partial Class of Student to add in the CourseID to the class so that I can also create a link between the two as I need to in a further question show all IPeople on a course. I take it an interface can display common values from two classes to create one list which can then be filtered.

So my question is. Am I getting this right so far? I've got no experience of this kind of work. If anyone could point me in the right direction for creating an interface that that would be great. Any example coding or websites.

Comment: If this is homework, you should state that. And please explain what linq and entity-framework have to do with this question. If they don't please remove these tags.

Comment: I've added the homework tag since this is very clearly homework

Comment: @Chris - clear to you, but this is something the OP should add, not you.

Comment: An interface called `IPeople`?  No wonder newbies fresh out of school have no sense in naming things.

Comment: You might start by google-ing or looking in your textbook for what an interface does/is.

Comment: I have removed the entityframework-4 tag, since this doesn't really have anything to do with EF4

Comment: Hi this isnt homework. I'm a VB.Net coder and I've applied for a Job as Junior Developer at a company. They've given me this exam knowing that I have no experience in C# or the entity framework but told me to use the internet to seek help if needed. I've been given 3 days to learn everything and answer this.

Comment: As for Text Books etc. I've never had any training in coding. I've been working as a hobby programmer for several years and been working full time as a programmer for a solicitors firm. I have used google and looked for what an interface is etc which is how I am getting to where I am in the question. I just wanted to know I wasn't barking down the wrong tree and going well off the mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To satisfy this, all you have to do is create the interface w/ the common properties you've identified, then in the partial classes have the two classes implement the interface, e.g.:

```
public partial class Student : IUniversityPerson{ ... }
```

where IUniversityPerson is the interface you've created. Linking course and so on isn't in the scope of the question as I read it.

Comment: Thank you for answering I am trying to come up with a solution now.

Answer (score 1):

A full answer here would take a lot of space. Entire chapters of many books have been devoted to topics like this. In general though, you are on the right track.

The problem you are likely having is that you are thinking about the design at too deep a level. That isn't your fault really. This question itself is troubling, and indicates that the person asking it is probably presenting the material at the wrong level of abstraction too.

The question's choice of IPeople isn't a good start (it should be IPerson), then it goes on to ask you to do OO design at a detailed level where you should be thinking about it from a much higher level. You should be thinking things like "student and teacher are both a kind of person", not thinking things like "student and teacher both have a field named LasteName".

Let me give you an example of how this question's too-deep level of abstraction is problematic. Thinking about it the way the question is asked means you will create an IPerson interface to represent the abstract concept of "a person". Student and Teacher both inherit this IPerson. So you design an interface that includes "all commonalities" between student and teacher (like the question says to do) and you come up with **StudentId, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, AverageScore, DepartmentId.** (as you indicated).

At that level of detail that is as good as it gets. But consider this: later you might need to add a class for the student's parents, thus giving you a third 'kind' of person. Would it make sense for Parent to have a DepartmentId field?

By thinking about the design at too deep a level of detail like this question encourages, you can (and will) end up with horribly brittle designs that don't make sense when viewed from a higher level of abstraction.

Comment: Thank you for an in depth answer to the question. They really thrown me in the deep end with the question but I do think I have the correct answer. I'm trying to work on the next part of the question which is to display a list of all IPeople in the system as an IENumberable of IPeople.

Comment: No problem; and don't sweat it. Based on how the question is worded, the people you have to impress to get the job aren't all that up on this stuff either (apparently). Any lack of existing skill with C# and OO itself is more than compensated for by your eagerness to learn, and resourcefulness to find the help you need online. That should count for a lot by itself :)

Comment: I am more than eager. I've been learning C# for a day now and I am loving every bit of it but learning without guidance is dangerous and I would prefer to be pointed in the right direction rather than wander aimlessly in wrong direction. Your answer was a relief to me as it did explain it. The wording of some of the questions make it difficult to understand when the reality is they only require a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've identified the common properties / members of the Teacher and Student objects. You dont need to add more unless the problem specifies to do so - simply make the interface for the intersecting members. You're about 50% there, so now you just need to make the interface and mark each class to implement it.

Comment: It doesn't require it at the moment but a seperate question relates to filtering that list by the CourseId. So I am presuming adding the CourseId to Teacher and Student Class will make that easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track... The commonality here is that Teacher and Student are both People.  So, you could create an `IPerson` interface, and a `Person` base class.  Then, both student and teacher would inherit from `Person` base class and both implement `IPerson` interface.

This kind of division allows you to separate the code needed for handling the requirements for a general "person" into separate modules.  It also allows for easier maintenance, as anytime a change is needed to the common "person" attributes, it's only needed in one place.  These are some of the basic principles of Object-Oriented programming.

Comment: Thank you for confirming I was in the right place. Its what I needed to know